# Remove a view when tapped outside its frame

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiview, frame

I am using a complex hierarchy of views and I want that when one of the subview is tapped outside its boundary its should be removed. I have tried using a transparent view with tap gesture but it does not allow me to use the above mentioned subview.

How do I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a hierarchy like below(Create XIB for this):

1) Create a transparent container view with full screen size and keep a reference to it

2) Add a transparent UIButton with full screen size and set its action method

3) Add your subView over the full screen transparent button

Now, display this container view whenever you want to display subView.
Whenever user taps outside the subView, your action method on button tap will be called. In this method you can remove the whole Container view using removeFromSuperView

Comment: I used tap gesture instead of button and used the tapped point to compare whether it lies in the particular view.

Answer (score 0):

```
[yourView removeFromSuperview]; /// if you want to show that view again you need to allocate it again.  
  (or)

[yourView setHidden:YES]; /// if you want to show that view again Just set it as NO.
```

Answer (score 0):

I will use the delegate at child controller  like

```
@protocol ViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)dismissPopupViewController;


@end
```

and set this to parent controller which brings the child controller and this method will dismiss the child controller.

Answer (score 0):

please use UITouch delegate methods :

– touchesBegan:withEvent:

– touchesMoved:withEvent:

– touchesEnded:withEvent:

– touchesCancelled:withEvent:

To get position of your subviews and manage accordingly.